# How to make sure all mp3s play at the same volume?

Tags: c#, audio, mp3, normalization, wmplayer

I'm making a music player in Winforms, C#. Some of my mp3s are softer than others.

Is there an easy method to normalize(is that the right word?) all my mp3s, so that no matter which I choose to play, they all play at the same standard volume?

Comment: Which language are you willing to use?

Comment: @filaton I'm using C# on Visual Studio, winforms.